# How to ensure that all WebAPI/OData requests pertain to a specific user?

Tags: rest, asp.net-mvc-4, odata, asp.net-web-api

I found this process simpler when consuming a WCF service (SOAP), but here goes...

Where Users 1..* Categories:

In exposing an OData RESTful service (MVC4, WebAPI, OData), client-side code could be issued like:

```
/odata/Categories?$filter=startswith(CategoryName,'paid')
```

Or even

```
/odata/Categories
```

Would return all categories for all users.  Not very secure.

I want to ensure that all requests issued when a user is logged in (I'm using forms authentication with my own custom role provider) only return data related to that user (where userID=x).  Is there a custom filter that needs to be created, whereby even if a logged in user saw the outgoing WebAPI/OData request paths (often defined in JavaScript), they can't try to get other user's information?

Each navigation property or related table in the db has a UserID field where the "AND UserID=x" could be used.

Would this involve creating some sort of `FilterQueryValidator` (actually query addition) similar to what's found at the bottom of [this](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/odata-support-in-aspnet-web-api/supporting-odata-query-options) page?

I'm just not sure on how this works, and would like some pointers.

FYI:  This may be related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20293423/how-to-use-a-mvc-webapi-odata-endpoint-securely) other question, but more specific on user-based requests.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a filter attribute or you can override GET / POST etc in your ODataContoller to add the UserID == X to the Linq expression.

e.g.

```
public override IQueryable<Product> Get()
{
   return _context.Products.Where(x => x.UserID == user_id);
}
```

Comment: can you please provide a sample of each proposed answer?