# How to add a .Net MVC request filter to prevent action calls based on role membership?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, membership-provider, roleprovider

In .Net MVC5, how would one add a request filter to prevent action calls based on role membership?

See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20293423/how-to-use-a-mvc-webapi-odata-endpoint-securely/20336730?noredirect=1#comment51521651_20336730) comment:

> wouldn't it make more sense to use a request filter to prevent the
>   action call on the controller in the event that the current user did
>   not have the right role membership instead of trying to mix the auth
>   logic in to the business logic?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My best solution for this is using:
    [AuthorizeAttribute]

You can place it as a normal attribute is used in c# mvc, like for ex:

```
 [Authorize]
 public ActionResult AuthenticatedUsers()
 {
     return View();
 }
```

You can also use it in top of the controller like this:

```
[Authorize]
 public class HomeController : Controller
 {
 }
```

And if you want it do be depedent on roles, you just simple give one parameter to this attribute like this:

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Admin, Super User")]
 public ActionResult AdministratorsOnly()
 {
     return View();
 }

 [Authorize(Users = "Betty, Johnny")]
 public ActionResult SpecificUserOnly()
 {
     return View();
 }
```

[Here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.authorizeattribute(v=vs.98).aspx) is some more detailed information for your question which I'd suggest would help you alot.

Good luck!